# Как вернуть true или false из промиса?

Tags: javascript

Как поменять данный метод так, чтобы он при успешном запросе возвращал true или false

```
const isClient = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stop();
            request('sign')
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.payload.response) {
                        const level = data.payload.accessLevel;
                        const isClient = level === CLIENT;

                        if (isClient) {
                            startPing();
                     //метод должен возвращать true
                        }
                    }
                     //метод должен возвращать false
                    resolve(isClient);
                })
                .catch(() => {
                  //метод должен возвращать false
                    reject(' error');
                });

    });
}
```

Comment: `new Promise` не нужен

Comment: убрал. но когда вызываю метод так
 const isOkSessionId = isClient();
возвращается undefined почему-то

Comment: потому что скорее всего ты убрал `return new Promise`, а не `new Promise` и теперь твоя функция ничего не возвращает. Что ты ожидаешь при этом вызове: `const isOkSessionId = isClient();`, что в `isOkSessionId` будет true или false?

Comment: да. если запрос прошел успешно, и полученный level === CLIENT, то возвращаем true 
если нет --false

Comment: @werty - https://pastebin.com/kfYQD82U
ну как то так